# Using a type as a value in typescript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I'm using `inject-loader` to mock dependencies for a Typescript project being unit tested.  The service I'm testing has an import line like this:

```
import pnp, { SearchQuery, Sort, SortDirection, CamlQuery } from "sp-pnp-js";
```

For my test, I want to mock several of the functions on pnp, but keep the classes intact.  In my unit test file, I've included this import:

```
import { SearchQuery, Sort, SortDirection, CamlQuery } from "sp-pnp-js";
```

Which gives my test access to the necessary classes.  I've declared a mock service object:

```
// mock services
const mockPnp = {
    default: { ... }
};
```

Which I'm wiring into my target class instance:

```
Service = require("inject!./sharepointservice")({
    "sp-pnp-js": mockPnp
}).Service;
```

And everything works, so long as I don't run any code that references those classes (ie. `SearchQuery`).  To get that to work, I tried adding it to the mock:

```
// mock services
const mockPnp = {
    default: { ... },
    SearchQuery: SearchQuery
};
```

However, I get a `'SearchQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` error.

I've tried casting to `any` (same error), tricks with modules and exports, with no luck.  I'm supposed to be able to write any Javascript with Typescript, and this would work trivially in Javascript - what am I missing here?

Comment: According to the [definition file](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/dist/pnp.d.ts#L910) `SearchQuery` is an interface, which means that you can not treat it as a value (as the error message says).  
Typescript interfaces aren't being compiled into the js output, and you can not use them at runtime.

Comment: I hadn't even thought to check if it was an interface - just assumed it was a type.  Let me find one of these I need that's a type and retry...

Comment: ...and the real types (like Search), work just fine.

Comment: @NitzanTomer - post that as an answer so I can mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [definition file](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/dist/pnp.d.ts#L910) `SearchQuery` is an interface, which means that you can not treat it as a value (as the error message says).

Typescript interfaces aren't being compiled into the js output, and you can not use them at runtime.

Comment: This looks like it's working - interface applied at compile time, so I don't need to fake them out in the mock, and I have no errors supplying real classes in the mock.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, since its just for type safety, I can do this
`t: MyInterface = {};`